# will the rays of a point source at definite distance reflect on a single point?

Tags: geometric-optics

In geometrical-optics it is always said that as far as the rays emitted from a source are paraxial, for an ideal optical system (say a circular concave mirror), all the rays do focus on a point which is the image of the source.

Is there some kind of proof for that?

PS: I guess there must be a way to show that the rays will pass through a single point independent of the angle of the emitted ray with respect to the axis of the mirror (but still paraxial)...

Comment: I am aware of the aberration of the light in the aspherical mirrors. My question mostly concerns just a single point source and its (I-don't-know-why) point image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paraxial rays from a point object do not in general focus at a single image point. This is only a limiting approximation for paraxial rays (ie small angles, close to the axis). So it is not possible to prove that it is true. Perhaps you are asking for a derivation of the thin lens equation? Easily found using an internet search.

The position of the image always depends on the angle which the ray makes with the optical axis. The approximation becomes better as the angle and height of the ray decreases to zero, but there is no point at which it is perfect. This is a form of spherical aberration. The aberration is small for paraxial rays but it is only zero in special cases, eg when the point object is at the centre of curvature of a spherical mirror.

Comment: Actually, the way these formulas are proved invoked the problem! Almost in all the formulas (lens/mirrors), in which we indeed deal with paraxial rays, there is an assumption, a statement that confuses me:

**All the (paraxial) rays of a source point will reflect into a single point. So drawing a few of them will uniquely determine the position of the image.**

This statement is seemed to be the definition of _ideal image_. That's fine. Yet, as I haven't seen any clue to support the idea that "_Yes, near the axis, we have nearly-ideal images_" I can't accept it easily.